# mapping a subset of core-data entities as a section-key-path

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a one-to-many relationship between:

```
Question<<---->Section
```

A section has many questions. A question has one section.

I now create a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get all questions seperated by its sections into UITableView-Sections.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MJUQuestion"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
    managedObjectContext:context
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"section.title" 
    cacheName:nil];
```

Now all questions get seperated into their corresponding sections which works but is not exactly what i want.

I don't want the questions of all sections, but i want all the questions of a specific subset of sections.

Sections are themselve seperated into categorys:

```
Section<<----->Category
```

And i only want the questions of sections that belong to a specific category.
if i would do a `NSFetchedResultsController` for Sections of that category i would add a predicate like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", category];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:projectPredicate];
```

But since this is not the case and i want them as section seperator, i'm not sure how to modify my `NSFetchRequest` properly.

So how do i need to modify my `NSFetchRequest` that i get the questions of a specific subset of sections and these sections as a UITableView-Section seperator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  You need to update your predicate and use a key path:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section.category IN %@", categoryArray];
```

Which will cause the request to check each question and see if its section's category is in the array.  This will filter you down to a subset of categories.